# Updated to 10.0.5, how to add Android SDK to existing project?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have update IntelliJ to the version 10.0.5. Old projects do not work as SDK is not specified. Where and how to specify Android SDK to existing projects?

Thanks

Comment: See http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/03/new-concept-of-android-sdk-in-intellij-idea-105/